# MySQL SELECT, UNION, JOIN query optimization

Tags: mysql, union

**Query Purpose:** The purpose of MySQL query is to find the timestamp difference between an event (`y.indicator = '1'`) and the row with the timestamp right before it. These occur multiple times across the database.

**Sample data:**

```
row_id | indicator | timestamp
----+---------+--------+----------------------------
abcdef | 0         | 1592900862 
abcdef | 0         | 1592900900 
abcdef | 1         | 1592900905 
abcdef | 1         | 1592900907
qrstuv | 0         | 1592900863 
qrstuv | 1         | 1592900867 
qrstuv | 0         | 1592900880 
qrstuv | 0         | 1592900900 
qrstuv | 1         | 1592900905
```

**Sample Output**

```
row_id | Diff      | timestamp
----+---------+--------+----------------------------
abcdef | 5         | 1592900905 
abcdef | 2         | 1592900907
qrstuv | 4         | 1592900867 
qrstuv | 5         | 1592900805
```

**The database**: requires a `UNION` of 16 different tables. The tables combined have 10s of millions of rows.

**The query work** when the condition `AND x.row_id IN ('abcde12242fdsdsfds','safzxvdseafcz')` only includes one `row_id`, **however breaks** when I add an additional `row_id` (therefore will break in the example below). I will need to run this on 20,000 `row_id`.

So to wind it down to two questions:

1. **Optimization:** How can I make my code more efficient so it will work on more than 1 row_id?
2. **Style:** Could I generated the `JOIN` table `y` without repeating the whole `UNION` statement.

```
SELECT x.row_id, x.timestamp, 
    MIN(x.timestamp - y.timestamp) AS Diff 
    FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM table01db.db
    UNION SELECT * FROM table02db.db
    UNION SELECT * FROM table03db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table04db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table05db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table06db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table07db.db
    UNION SELECT * FROM table08db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table09db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table10db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table11db.db
    UNION SELECT * FROM table12db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table13db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table14db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table15db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table16db.db ) AS x
    JOIN (SELECT * FROM table01db.db
    UNION SELECT * FROM table02db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table03db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table04db.db
    UNION SELECT * FROM table05db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table06db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table07db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table08db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table09db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table10db.db
    UNION SELECT * FROM table11db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table12db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table13db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table14db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table15db.db 
    UNION SELECT * FROM table16db.db ) AS y
    ON x.row_id = y.row_id
    WHERE x.indicator = '1' 
    AND x.timestamp > y.timestamp
    AND x.row_id IN ('abcde12242fdsdsfds','safzxvdseafcz')
    GROUP BY x.row_id, x.timestamp
```

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: Is it really necessary to do a sort and remove duplicate rows?  The `UNION ALL` set operator concatenates the sets, and is much faster than the `UNION` operation which requires operations to identify and remove duplicate rows.

Comment: it seems like it would be much more efficient if the individual SELECT statements included the `WHERE row_id IN` condition, then MySQL could make efficient use of an available index on each table. As written, it seems like it's forcing MySQL to materialize some hugh jass intermediate sets. What does EXPLAIN output show?